# How to limit number of entries from GeoDjango Postgis django-rest-framework query?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postgis, geodjango

I've built basic Django mapping functionality through [this tutorial](https://www.paulox.net/2021/07/19/maps-with-django-part-2-geodjango-postgis-and-leaflet/) but Python keeps blowing through 32GB of ram and/or the browser crashes, presumably because the query isn't limited to the first n results and the DB has millions of entries.

My "vietsets.py":

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework_gis import filters

from core.models import Tablename
from core.serializers import MarkerSerializer

class MarkerViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    bbox_filter_field = "geom"
    filter_backends = (filters.InBBoxFilter,)
    queryset = Tablename.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MarkerSerializer
```

I think `InBBoxFilter` needs to be elaborated upon but [the docs](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-gis/#inbboxfilter) don't seem to mention any further options. The docs say "if you are using other filters, you’ll want to include your other filter backend in your view" giving the example, `filter_backends = (InBBoxFilter, DjangoFilterBackend,)`, but I only want to limit the number of results for the functionality `InBBoxFilter` already provides. Can I write some kind of `DjangoFilterBackend` to limit results? Or is this best addressed through django-rest-framework functionality?

How can I tell it to limit the number of results, or otherwise improve performance when using big databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to below.
This pagination is supported by restframework_gis.

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework_gis import filters
from rest_framework_gis.pagination import GeoJsonPagination

from core.models import Tablename
from core.serializers import MarkerSerializer


class MarkerViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    bbox_filter_field = "geom"
    filter_backends = (filters.InBBoxFilter,)
    queryset = Tablename.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MarkerSerializer
    pagination_class = GeoJsonPagination
```

You can upgrade your server or limit the result(pagination).
Most appropriate pagination is up to your request.
You can grouping area by some rule or whatever.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Any idea on how to stop the browser from keeping markers in memory? And suggestions for where to read up more on `rest_framework_gis`? [The only docs I could find](https://github.com/openwisp/django-rest-framework-gis) seem to assume a high level of knowledge

Comment: Browser job is done by JS. You need to read JS you insert on template. Read for what purpose? Pagination?

Comment: Pagination, rate limiting, and other basic things beginners should learn about. Ideally something with simple reproducible examples

Comment: @ChrisDixon For pagination, read DRF and Django official docs. Rate limiting is not mine. Other basic things depend on what you build.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pagination`
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework_gis import filters
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

from core.models import Tablename
from core.serializers import MarkerSerializer

    
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000


class MarkerViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    bbox_filter_field = "geom"
    filter_backends = (filters.InBBoxFilter,)
    queryset = Tablename.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MarkerSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination

# request host/api/<your_url>?page=<page_num>&page_size=<page_size>
# will limit size of your response
# and response will include current_page, number_of_elements and  last_page.
```

Comment: This stops it from crashing but also from any markers loading. Is pagination most appropriate? We're not trying to paginate anything, only limit results. And what's `host/api/<your_url>?page=<page_num>&page_size=<page_size>` for?

Comment: @ChrisDixon I misunderstand your question. I rewrite answer.